# For each listbox item in variable

Tags: c#, foreach, listbox

somehow i seem to be blind this morning ;)
i have the following code[1] which does read
the object collection out of an ListBox.
with the string b i can "retrieve" the strings

in b there are filenames and directory paths stored
that i want to backup with xcopy code [2].

Code:

```
private void btnBenutz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblAusgabe2.Text = "";
    ListBox.ObjectCollection a = listBox1.Items;
    foreach (string x in a)
    {
        b = x;
        lblAusgabe2.Text += "\n" + b;
    }
}
```

More code:

```
 Process.Start("XCOPY.EXE", "/E /I /Y" + b + pfadauswahl + "\\Backup\\" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\\UserData\\");
```

how can i use b as an array which i probably have to ? otherwise only the first item will always been read out? Also the process start i have to use outside of the btnBenutz... so some variable has to be initialized in the public partial class Form2 : Form

Comment: What are you trying to do? I guess, you a have a list of file names in the `ListBox`, and you want to copy them all in another directory. Am I right?

Comment: almost... i wanna copy them yes.... but somehow i am missing out on an string array... all examples that are shown below are only usable if i do the foreach within the btnBenutz_Click... i need the foreach to work like 300 lines below...

Answer (score 1):

Define `b` as `List<string>`. You also use a better name like `fileNameList`:

```
private List<string> fileNameList; // a class field, not a local variable
```

Then add the file names to the list:

```
private void btnBenutz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblAusgabe2.Text = "";
    ListBox.ObjectCollection a = listBox1.Items;
    foreach (string x in a)
    {
        fileNames.Add(x);
        lblAusgabe2.Text += Environment.NewLine + x; // Why are you doing this?
    }
}
```

Then in another place, run the `xopy` command for each file:

```
foreach(string fileName in fileNameList)
{
    Process.Start("XCOPY.EXE", "/E /I /Y " + fileName + pfadauswahl + "\\Backup\\" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\\UserData\\");
}
```

if that's what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: thats exactly what i want to achieve ;) thank you...
fileNames.Add(x); where needs that to be defined?

Comment: @incubuzz1978 Define `fileNameList` outside of any method. No matter where, just in the form class. See [Fields in C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnBenutz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string x in listBox1.Items)
    {
        sb.Append("\n" + x);
    }
    // then use sb.ToString() somewhere...
}
```

Comment: Maybe better `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: hey dennis , thank you for your replay... looks good to me--- how could the string builder be initialized globally?

Comment: @incubuzz1978: what do you mean " initialized globally"? you can declare class field instead of local variable.

Comment: i need to declare the sb ahead of the button so i can use it "outside" of it... thats what i mean by globally...

Answer (score 0):

As you commented you want to call it from other places also like another button click then
Do something like this :

1) Declare list of string at class level

```
 List<string> fileNameList ;
```

2) Create a function with some meaningfull name let's say StartXcopy like below

```
public void StartXcopy()
{
       ListBox.ObjectCollection a = listBox1.Items;
       fileNameList = new List<string>();
       foreach (string x in a)
       {
            fileNameList.Add(x);
            lblAusgabe2.Text += "\n" + x;
       }

       foreach (string filename in fileNameList)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("XCOPY.EXE", "/E /I /Y" + filename  + pfadauswahl + "\\Backup\\" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\\UserData\\");
       }
}
```

3) Then call this function from where you want, like below in button click

```
 private void btnBenutz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      lblAusgabe2.Text = "";
      StartXcopy(); 
 }
```

**Note** : Here i am assuming you are always iterating through  listBox1 items.

Comment: problem is ... the foreach can't be used with the button...
the code is like 500 lines beyond the button... so i have to
declare b and filenamelist globally

Comment: i want to use if we take this example the foreach outside of the button... e.g. in another button...